# Flask cookie expiration date in local time

Tags: python, flask

Can anyone please tell me how to set the cookie expiration so that it's so the date is in the local timezone and not UTC? I need to set a cookie expiration date to 30 minutes after it's been created, the only issue is that the cookie creation date is in the local timezone and the expiration date is in UTC, so if the user is in a UTC+ timezone, the cookie is never created.

I've tried setting the exp. date using `datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=float(30))`, where `datetime.now()` returns local time, but it seems Flask converts that to UTC.

Edit: cookie creation:

```
 if 'access_token' and 'expire_in' in auth_tokens:
    expire_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=float(auth_tokens['expire_in']))
    response.set_cookie('access_token', str(auth_tokens['access_token']), expires=expire_date, secure=is_secure, httponly=False)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show more code please? specifically how you create the cookie?

Comment: Sure thing, edited the comment with updated code.

Comment: Why not use `max_age=timedelta(minutes=30)` instead of setting an absolute `expires` ? Also - your `if` condition isn't doing what you think it is, you most likely want: `if 'access_token' in auth_tokens and 'expire_in' in auth_tokens`...

Comment: Thanks, the max_age solved it.

Comment: Apparently Microsoft Edge (and IE) doesn't yet support `Max-age` for cookies... so that one would be one to stick with `Expires`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per Jon Clements' comment setting `max_age=timedelta(minutes=30)` solves the issue.